# Adjacency matrix from edge list in R

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, sna

I have an unweighted edge list which I need to convert to a symmetric matrix for futher analysis. I use `igraph` function `graph.data.frame()` to create a graph object. Unfortunatelly I can't find a way to convert `dgCMatrix` to a matrix or creat a matrix right from the edge list. I'm sure there should be a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph.data.frame is GDF then you can get a sparse data matrix from

```
as_adjacency_matrix(GDF)
```

This is the dgCMatrix that you mention. But now you can just use

```
as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(GDF))
```

if you want the full matrix.